# How to locate the peak of the convolution of two log-concave distributions?

Tags: convolution, numerical-integration

The convolution of two log-concave distributions is also log-concave. It follows that it has a single local maximum. Assume that $f$ and $g$ are two log-concave distributions and that you know where the maximum is located for each. Is there an easy algorithm to locate the maximum of the convolution $f*g$? That is, minimizing the number of evaluations of the convolution, since it is numerically expensive.

Comment: Personally, I'd start a search near the sum of the modes. There might be a way of getting useful bounds out of the log-concavity to allow a bounded search, but I can't say I know of one.

Answer (score 2):

Given that the convolution is log-concave, one could use a simple Newton-Raphson algorithm, which is difficult to beat when it works.

Comment: That requires numerical evaluation of the derivative of the convolution. Is there a way to circumvent this?

Comment: Not really? You can use non-derivative based methods, but they will usually involve many more evaluations of the target function, and really are more useful when your function is $not$ log-concave, so I don't think that's what you want. It seems like you could use information about $f$ and $g$ to get a reasonable starting value though.

Comment: The derivative of a convolution has a nice property: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/177239/derivative-of-convolution, this should ease the derivative calculation.